# Evaluating $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {n}{n^4+4} $

Tags: sequences-and-series

I tried the method of differences. For $n^4+n^2+1$ the terms cancel out, but here they don't cancel. I am not able to proceed further.

Comment: The sum is telescoping, you just need to make some effort to see it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice $$\begin{align}\frac{n}{n^4+4} 
&= \frac{n}{(n^2+2)^2 - 4n^2} = \frac{n}{(n^2-2n+2)(n^2+2n+2)}\\
&= \frac14\left[\frac{1}{(n-1)^2+1}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2+1}\right]\\
&= \frac14\left[\left(\frac{1}{(n-1)^2+1} + \frac{1}{n^2+1}\right)-\left(\frac{1}{n^2+1} + \frac{1}{(n+1)^2+1}\right)\right]
\end{align}
$$
is a telescoping series,
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{n^4+4} = \frac14\left[\frac{1}{0^2+1}+\frac{1}{1^2+1} \right] = \frac38$$